# Assigning in Python, Arrays

Tags: python, arrays, variable-assignment

I am creating an array of random values so that I can do different sorts and see how all of them interact.  The problem is that when I call a sort on an array, I cannot then use that array again because it was already sorted.  I just dont seem to understand how python works with assignments.  To me, it looks like assigning an array to another array share a memory address.  Can some one please how assigning arrays works in python and explain to me why my code doesnt work.

Here is where I call my insertion sort.  The goal is to have insertion_sort_array correctly sorted while random_test_array_10 to remain unsorted.

```
for i in random_array_10:
print i

time.sleep(2)

print "Insertion Sort"

with timer.Timer() as t:
    insertion_sort_array = sorts.insertion_sort(random_array_10).isort()

print t.interval

for i in random_array_10:
   print i
```

Here is my insertion sort class

```
class insertion_sort():

    def __init__(self, array):
        self.array = array

    def isort(self):
        for i in range(1, len(self.array)):
            temp = self.array[i]
            k = i
            while k > 0 and temp < self.array[k-1]:
                self.array[k] = self.array[k-1]
                k = k-1
            self.array[k] = temp
        return self.array
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both `self.array` and `array` are pointing to the same object (the same mutable list). To make a copy of the list, you could use the `list()` constructor in `__init__`:

```
self.array = list(array)
```

As a plus side, it makes any other iterables be allowed as inputs for your insertion sort.

Comment: Although it's notable that if he does this, he will be timing both copying the array and sorting it.